# Allocating memory for a structure within a structure

Tags: c, struct, malloc

```
typedef struct{
    char id[15];
    int count;
}hashtag;

typedef struct node{
    hashtag *hashtag;
    struct node*next;
}*link;
```

I'm writing a program to read hashtags from a sentence, and I want to store them in a list. I've already defined this two structures, and I can read and pass the hashtags to the function below but I need help allocating memory in order to copy the string to the list.

```
void check_insert(char newh[]){
    link x;
    //malloc to allocate memory for the string I want to copy

    strcpy(x->hashtag->id, newh);
    x->hashtag->count += 1;
    head = insert_end(head, x->hashtag); //head is a global variable that points to the 1st element of the list
}
```

Comment: you could use strdup instead of strcpy

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand and what you need help with. You already know you can call `malloc` to allocate memory. So what precisely is it you don't understand how to do?

Comment: `link x = malloc(sizeof(*x)); x->hashtag = malloc(sizeof(*x->hashtag));`

Comment: Are you sure you initialized `x->hashtag->count` before adding 1 to it?

Comment: 1) You don't have a "`struct` in a `struct`. A pointer is not a struct! (Is it really neccessary to state?) 2) `link` is not a `struct`, but a pointer, too. 3) Don't `typedef` pointers!

Comment: What text or who suggested typedef'ing a pointer like `typedef struct node{ hashtag *hashtag;  struct node*next; }*link;` instead of `typedef struct node{ hashtag *hashtag;  struct node*next; }link;`  (no `*` before `link`)?

Comment: why don't you just make `struct node` contain `hashtag` instead of a pointer to one?

Answer (score 1):

You should allocate and initialize the pointer `x` in `check_insert`, it is undefined behavior to dereference it and access its members without allocation first:

```
void check_insert(char newh[]){
    link x = malloc(sizeof *x);
    x->hashtag = malloc(sizeof *x->hashtag);

    // strcpy(x->hashtag->id, newh); <-- UB if newh is larger than 14 in size
    x->hashtag->id[0] = '\0';
    strncat(x->hashtag->id, newh, sizeof(x->hashtag->id));
    x->hashtag->count = 1;
    head = insert_end(head, x->hashtag);
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(x->hashtag->id, newh);` is susceptible to overruns.  Could use `x->hashtag->id[0] = '\0'; strncat(x->hashtag->id, newh, sizeof(x->hashtag->id));`